# How to get values from editable PDF's field values.?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe

I have an editable PDF (Users can fill the form online) which I populated that inside an IFrame.

I have a server side Button outside the IFrame control. When i hit that button,

I need to get the PDF's Fields and its corresponding values. RAD PDF is a third party tool which provide my need.

But is there any other tool or any other way, where I can get the values from the PDF's fields...?

Comment: Have you had any traction on this at all?  We have a solution that we are working with now called PDF4NET but what we have is an html file that has the content of the pdf with form fields and then we merge the editable pdf with the values from the POST...shout if you get any answers on this...I would be curious.

Answer (score 0):

Start getting used to [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)/ Its a free library for creating/editing PDF files in asp.net.

For this one, you want to be looking at the Acrofields.

Likes these examples:

http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/
http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_fill.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PdfGenerator_CS06162007023347AM/PdfGenerator_CS.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I didn't notice that you already use a 3rd party tool. I'm not familier with that one, though if it can't do what you need, iTextSharp will...

Comment: anybody care to say why the downvote? feedback is always better than click and run....